# Ionic project built with docker do not load static files

Tags: docker, ionic-framework, dockerfile

I have an Ionic project already working and running. I wanted to dockerize it so I wrote and added Dockerfile and .dockerignore to it manually. My project structure looks like following:

[image]

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "example: An Ionic project",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-messages": "^1.5.1",
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "android"
  ]
}
```

My bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "HelloIonic",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.1",
    "angular-route": "~1.3.1",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.0",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "~0.1.5",
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "ngDialog": "~0.3.3",
    "underscore": "~1.7.0",
    "ionic": "^1.2.4",
    "angular-resource": "^1.5.2",
    "angular-google-chart": "^0.1.0",
    "angular-ui-router-styles": "^1.1.0",
    "angular-audio": "^1.7.2"
  },

    "resolutions": {
      "angular": "~1.3.1"
    }

}
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:4.0

COPY . /www/app

RUN npm install -g ionic cordova
RUN npm install -g bower
RUN npm install -g gulp

WORKDIR /www/app
RUN npm install
RUN echo '{"allow_root":true}' > /root/.bowerrc
RUN bower install

EXPOSE 8100 35729

ENTRYPOINT ["ionic"]
CMD ["serve", "--all", "--port", "8100", "--livereload-port", "35729"]
```

And .dockerignore:

```
Dockerfile
config.xml
.sass-cache
.editorconfig
.io-config.json
.dockerignore

hooks/
platforms/
node_modules/
resources/
plugins/
www/css/*.css

*.zip
*.tar*
```

It is built successfully (I guess, as there are no errors) but when I execute `docker build -t ionic-preview .` but when I run it with `docker run -p 8100:8100 -it ionic-preview` - > it runs but no static files are loaded.

Is there anything wrong with my dockerfile? Or what is the issue?

**UPDATE:**
When normally I run my application, I see like following:
[image]

With docker I see this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You did not share your data yet as in: `-v /src/webapp:/webapp`

So you could do:

```
docker run -p 8100:8100 -v /src/webapp:/webapp -it ionic-preview
```

Change the maps to your maps.

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#locating-a-volume

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: I did this, but still facing the same problem :(

Comment: What do you exactly mean with static files, the project files as shown in your first image, are not available in the container? Can you post the command you used for running the container with the volume?

Comment: I mean css (perhaps HTML as well) are missing. See the screenshots I have updated in question. I did build with `docker build -t ionic-preview .` and then when it was done: `docker run -p 8100:8100 -v /src/webapp:/webapp -it ionic-preview`

Comment: you have to change the `/src/webapp:/webapp` maps to how your maps are called. The first one is on the host relative to the docker compose file and the second one is the destination on the container.